# Behavior of parenthesis in for loop variable declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does the usage of parentheses have any effect whatsoever in the variable declaration syntax of a Python for loop?

Example 1: basic for loop declaring `i` with no parenthesis

```
>>> for i in range(0,10): print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Basic for loop declaring `i` with arbitrary parentheses

```
for (((((i))))) in range(0,10): print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

For loop which unpacks two values, declared with no parentheses

```
>>> for x,y in zip(range(0,10), range(0,10)):  print(x,y)
...
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

Same thing, but with parenthesis around x, y, and both.

```
>>> for ((x),(y)) in zip(range(0,10), range(0,10)):  print(x,y)
...
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

So it seems the parentheses have no effect - they are not interpreted as creating, for example, a tuple.  Am I correct, or is there any reason to use parentheses in a for loop variable declaration?

You can even, apparently, say this:

```
>>> for [x,y] in zip(range(0,10), range(0,10)):  print(x,y)
...
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

...and the list notation (brackets) appear to have no effect either.

Comment: No, there's not. Parentheses doesn't do anything in your code. If you want to construct a tuple, do it as `(value,)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any reason to use parentheses in a for loop variable
>   declaration?

Yes, you need them to unpack more complex iterables.  Specifically, nested iterables such as this one:

```
enumerate(zip(range(10), range(10, 20)))
```

Using parenthesis, everything works fine:

```
>>> for x, (y, z) in enumerate(zip(range(10), range(10, 20))):
...    print("x=", x, "y=", y, "z=", z)
...
x= 0 y= 0 z= 10
x= 1 y= 1 z= 11
x= 2 y= 2 z= 12
x= 3 y= 3 z= 13
x= 4 y= 4 z= 14
x= 5 y= 5 z= 15
x= 6 y= 6 z= 16
x= 7 y= 7 z= 17
x= 8 y= 8 z= 18
x= 9 y= 9 z= 19
>>>
```

because `x, (y, z)` matches the structure of the iterables returned by:

```
enumerate(zip(range(10), range(10, 20)))
```

---

Without the parenthesis however, you will raise a `ValueError`:

```
>>> for x, y, z in enumerate(zip(range(10), range(10, 20))):
...    print("x=", x, "y=", y, "z=", z)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
>>>
```

because Python sees `x, y, z` and therefore expects:

```
enumerate(zip(range(10), range(10, 20)))
```

to return three-item iterables when it only returns two-item ones (tuples with a number and another two-item tuple):

```
>>> for item in enumerate(zip(range(10), range(10, 20))):
...     print(item)
...
(0, (0, 10))
(1, (1, 11))
(2, (2, 12))
(3, (3, 13))
(4, (4, 14))
(5, (5, 15))
(6, (6, 16))
(7, (7, 17))
(8, (8, 18))
(9, (9, 19))
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Just** parenthesis around an expression only act to group the expression (to override operator precedence, to be able to span multiple lines, etc.).

If you wanted to create tuples, use a *comma*:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1,
(1,)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of the empty tuple `()`, it is not the parentheses which define a tuple, it's the commas. Parentheses simply keep the tuple items separate from surrounding code.

```
# These are all identical: x is a tuple with 2 elements.
x = (1, 2)
(x) = (1, 2)
x = 1, 2
(x) = 1, 2

# These are all identical: x is assigned the first element of the tuple (1, 2)
x, = (1, 2)
(x,) = (1, 2)
x, = 1, 2
(x,) = 1, 2
```